# How to check if a range in a list is the same?

Tags: python

I want to check if a certain range in a list is the same. For example:
In a list I have `[X,Y,X,X,X,Y,Y]`, and I want to see if the third, fourth, and fifth are the same.

I have tried the following:

```
list = ['X', 'Y', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'Y']
for i in list, range(2,4):
    if not i == 'X':
        print("Test")
```

It *does* work, prints `Test` twice.

```
Test
Test
```

I just don't want to write a bunch of this:

`if` ... `and` .... `and` ..... `and` ... `or` .... `and` ...

Comment: That's not how you slice lists.  Read [Python's list slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation) to learn how.  What you are actually doing is forming a tuple `(list, range(2, 4))` and iterating over that.  Neither of those values is equal to `X`, so it prints twice.  As an aside "not equals" is more naturally expressed as `i != 'X'`

Comment: "I want to check if a certain range in a list" The problem here is trying to apply English grammar to a programming problem. The list does not *contain* any ranges, so the `range` function should not be expected to have **anything to do with** the solution. Though a range **contains indices** that could in turn be used to index the list and get its elements, a much more natural approach is to **slice** the list, and then do a test on the entire slice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looping such that you test `not list == 'X'` then `not range(2, 4) == 'X'`; obviously, neither is equal, so you print both times. Your logic can be dramatically simplified though. If the goal is to see if indices 2, 3 and 4 are all equal, just convert that slice of the list to a `set` and check if the length is 1:

```
mylist = ['X', 'Y', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'Y']  # Changed list name; naming the list "list" leads to tears
if len(set(mylist[2:5])) == 1:
    print("2, 3 and 4 equal")
else:
    print("At least one not equal to the others")
```

You may also wish to check that `mylist` is long enough (slicing will not raise an error if the slice doesn't get the three elements expected), as written this only tests that the list is at least 3 elements long and any elements from index 2 to 4 are equal if they exist.

If you *know* `mylist` will always have at least five elements, and you *prefer* an exception when it is not, another solution is to check:

```
if mylist[2] == mylist[3] == mylist[4]:
    print("2, 3 and 4 equal")
else:
    print("At least one not equal to the others")
```

It's more verbose, but Python's chained comparisons mean you only load each value once, and unlike the other solution, it short-circuits; if index `2` is not equal to index `3`, it won't even bother to load index `4`, let alone compare it to the others.

Comment: Thanks! This Really helped, also now I can make my previous code better!

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is more elegant way to do that, but you can try that:

```
def check_same(mylist, start_index, end_index):
    value = mylist[start_index]   
    for element in mylist[start_index + 1 : end_index]:
    if not element == value:
        return False
    return True
```

Comment: Please use the usual 4 white space indents